# Line Input error excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having this compile error : "Expected: End of statement" and I just don't understand why
The code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, posLat As Integer, posLong As Integer
myFile = "E:\output.txt"
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Open myFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
       Line Input #1,textline
   text = text & textline
Loop
Close #1

End Sub
```

The error is at line "Line Input #1,textline"
Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: It seems strange that the IDE hasn't inserted a space in between `#1,` and `textline`.  The code as posted compiles for me, so perhaps there is an unprintable character on that line which has disappeared as you posted it here.  Try deleting the line (and perhaps the next line) and retyping it.  Maybe the line includes actual tab characters at the start - that might explain the strange indentation.

Comment: You only need `myFile = "E:\output.txt"` **OR** `myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()` but not both. And this code works. If you still get an error please say what error you get.

Comment: @YowE3K  , I deleted that line and wrote it again and it worked! Thank you very much!