# Remove first two quotes from lines more than 20 characters long

Tags: vba, excel

I've not written any VBA for a few years so am rusty and would apprecite some help.

I have a file with around 9k lines of text, I need a script that will go through and remove the first two quotation marks from any rows with more than 20 characters.

How can I do that?

Update:

I have this that picks out the rows with more than 20 chars but not sure how to remove the first two quotes:

```
Sub Sanitise()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rw As Range

RowCount = 0

Set sh = ActiveSheet
For Each rw In sh.Rows

    If Len(sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value) > 20 Then
    ' Need to remove the first two quotes
    End If

Next rw

End Sub
```

Data:

> A00,408,"UXS",201309,10X641,00110 U02,99400,"200X601","E","N","38418","       064X09","00","","","","","
>   ","","","E","","" S72,"MXRE0042" S72,"MRE0047" S72,"MRE0047"
>   U02,7514100,"201613","E","N","66620","
>   21011X","00","","","","","  ","","","E","","" S72,"MRE00432"
>   S72,"MRE00457" S72,"MRE00417" U02,7513770602,"20X12","E","N","40761","
>   12775X","00","","","","","  ","","","E","","" S72,"MRE00432"
>   S72,"MRE00X47" S72,"MRE004X7"

Comment: Here is a post which is quite recent and gets you to open your text file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088103/line-input-error-excel-vba Each line of text will be pulled into the string variable `textline`. Then you can check the length of the string with `Len(textline)` if it is greater than 20 and check with `InStr` if there are any quotation marks in there to remove. Yet, I am not sure what you want to do once the quotation marks are gone. Do you want to write back to the text file or put it into an Excel sheet?

Comment: Thanks, I just want to remove the quotes so leave everything else as-is.

Comment: Do you have some example data for us to use?

Comment: we would need to an example of the text

Comment: so is the text always so structured? You can do a left until the first quote, then a right from the second quote and a mid for the text within the quote. essentially left&mid&right, while removing the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will go through Column A and use a variant array to remove the first two `"` in strings longer than 20 characters.

The code dumps the updated strings to Column B.

```
Sub CrankyKohli()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim x

Set rng1 = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
x = rng1.Value

For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(x)
    If Len(x(lngCnt, 1)) > 20 Then x(lngCnt, 1) = Replace(x(lngCnt, 1), """", vbNullString, , 2)
Next

rng1.Offset(0, 1) = x

End Sub
```